Eliminacion Gaussiana por pivotaje Python IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
Buenas noches comunidad
Estoy haciendo un codigo de phyton para eliminicaion gaussiana por pivotaje. Me piden resolver una matriz 4x4 pero al momento de correr el codigo me sale este error.
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
este es el codigo que estoy utilizando
import numpy
m = 4
n = 5
matrix=numpy.zeros((m,n))
vector=numpy.zeros((n))
x=numpy.zeros((m))
print('Introduce la matriz de coeficientes y el vector de solucion')
for r in range(0,m):
    for c in range(0,n):
        matrix[(r),(c)]=(input("Elemento a["+str(r+1)+","+str(c+1)+"]"))
vector[(r)]= (input('b['+str(r+1)+']: '))
print(matrix)
for k in range(0,m):
    for r in range(k+1,m):
        factor=(matrix[r,k]/matrix[k,k])
        vector[r]=vector[r]-(factor*vector[k])
for c in range(0,n):
    matrix[r,c]=matrix[r,c]-(factor*matrix[k,c])
x[m-1]=vector[m-1]/matrix[m-1,m-1]
print(x[m-1])
for r in range(m-2,-1,-1):
    suma=0
    for c in range(0,n):
        suma=suma+matrix[r,c]*x[c]
x[r]=(vector[r]-suma)/matrix[r,r]
print('Resultado Matriz')
print(matrix)
print('Resultado del Vector')
print(vector)
print('Resultados')
print(x)

me marca el error en suma=suma+matrix[r,c]*x[c]
Agradezco su colaboración.

El problema del error está dentro del bucle: for c in range(0,n): Como es una matriz rectangular 4 x 5 (NO cuadrada), la cantidad de columnas n no coincide con la cantidad de elementos de vector, que está creado a partir de las filas m. Asi que cuando llega al último elemento de n, se desborda el iterador del vector. Prueba el código con una matriz cuadrada. || Por lo demás, no recuerdo mucho de análisis numérico; si nadie más ayuda, puedes echarle un ojo a las respuestas del sitio en inglés.
